# How to trim the protocol from a URL in a Twig Template for Grav CMS

Tags: twig, grav

I'm needing to output a URL without the protocol (http: or https:) from a twig template usin Grav CMS.

What is the best way to do this?

Twig provides a [MATCH function for comparisons](https://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/templates.html#comparisons)  that uses regex, and a [REPLACE function](https://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/filters/replace.html) that does not use regex.

Therefore, it seems I am stuck with doing a convoluted if statement such as:

`

```
    {% if url starts with 'https:' %}   
        {{ url|replace('https:') }}
    {% else %}

        {% if url starts with 'http:' %}
            {{ url|replace('http:') }}
        {% else %}
            {{ url }}
        {% endif %}
```

`

Is there a better way of doing this feat? If I put this code in a macro, how can I utilize the macro? Here is the complete macro:

`

```
{% macro fixUrl(url) %}
    {% if url %}
        {% if url starts with 'https:' %}   
            {{ url|replace('https:') }}
        {% else %}

            {% if url starts with 'http:' %}
                {{ url|replace('http:') }}
            {% else %}
                {{ url }}
            {% endif %}
        {% endif %}
    {% endif %}

{% endmacro %}
```

`

And I call macro like: `<meta property="og:url" content="{{ self.fixUrl(page.url()) }}" />`

I'm getting an empty string when I call this macro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've discovered that Grav CMS provides a [regex_replace](https://learn.getgrav.org/themes/twig-filters-functions#regex-replace) function.

Here is my solution:

`<meta property="og:url" content="{{ page.url()|regex_replace('/^https?:/', '') }}" />`